# Каково происхождение слов «пьеса», «песо» и «песок»?

Tags: этимология

Можно ли предполагать родство корней в словах: «пьеса» (театральн.), «песо» (платежн.) и «песок» (пляжн.),  учитывая сходство их звучания и частичное совпадение значений?
Слово «песок» считают исконным или относят к заимствованиям?

Answer (score 1):

- Про слово *песок* известно мало, за исключением того, что оно имеет
  общеславянскую основу *пъс*. От этой же основы образовано слово
  *супесь*. Это не заимствование [(Словари)](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA).
- *Пьеса* — слово предположительно с кельтским корнем, означающим *кусок*, но в русский язык пришло не напрямую, а через французский или немецкий, где имеет схожие значения: *вещь, часть* и т.п. [(Словари](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0) + [Викисловарь)](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0#%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F).
- Название монеты песо на испанском означает *масса*. Происходит от
  латинского pensum (это форма Supinum Primum от слова *pendo*,
  переводящегося как *"взвешивать"*), а в латинский пришло из
  праиндоевр. *(s)pen(d) *«тянуть»* [(Викисловарь)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peso#Spanish).

**Родственных связей между этими тремя словами нет.**

Comment: Сначала термином «песо» называли небольшие, но одинаковые по размеру, серебряные слитки (куски)… https://utmagazine.ru/posts/13486-peso  Значение «взвешивать» могло быть уже вторичным.

Comment: @guaranteen во-первых, в статье написано "считается", а подобные абстрактные бездоказательные выражения не имеют веса. Кем "считается", почему "считается"?.. Во-вторых, значение "взвешивать" не могло быть вторичным, потому что изначально слово произошло от латинского слова, переводящегося как "взвешивать". Если что и может быть вторичным значением, так это значение "одинаковые серебряные слитки".

Comment: ПЕСО (исп. peso – вес, кусок) – денежная единица ряда стран. В названии монеты отражен тот факт, что испанцы … делили слитки серебра на равные куски – «песо» и использовали их как деньги… Позднее испанский талер в Америке получил название …П. дуро (duro – тяжелый).
https://www.biznesbooks.com/components/com_jshopping/files/demo_products/gukasyan-g-m-ekonomika-ot-a-do-ya.pdf

Comment: Отсюда видно, что Викисловарь «утаивает» от нас важную информацию о слове «песо». Однако, она легко обнаруживается при переводе «piece» с латыни или английского на русский.
Заметим, что в давние времена наши рубли (как и песо) тоже были "кусочками", поскольку целое рубят на части - "куски".

Comment: @guaranteen если вам кажется, что кто-то что-то от вас утаивает, рекомендую купить себе шапочку из фольги. И избавьте уже меня от ваших этимологических потуг, хорошо? В латыни слова piece вообще нет. // Не нравится мой ответ — поставили минус, прошли мимо, написали свой (здесь можно отвечать на собственные вопросы). В диспуты я вступать с вами не намерен.

Comment: https://briefly.ru/shukshin/srezal/